# TinyMCE shows "domain not registered"

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-5

I self-hosted (on a S3 CDN) the TinyMCE by following the steps here:
https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/self-host-tinymce/

But still, I'm getting a "domain not registered" error.

My code is as simple as this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.******.com/slimmed/plugins/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
    <script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '.description'
        });
    </script>
```

Hope someone can shed a light on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

no need to register your domain, just add this css to hide the notification :)

```
<style>

.tox-notifications-container{
    display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It lookks like TinyMCE gets confused when you add parameters in react, whether it is self-hosted or not. It is definitely a bug on their part.

Answer (score -1):

If you are self hosting TinyMCE you should not be getting a "domain not registered" error.  The need to register domains is specific to our Cloud platform so if you are seeing some sort of domain error you are likely accidentally pulling TinyMCE from our Cloud platform.

Are you using a web framework like Vue/React?  If you look through your codebase do you see any script tags that look like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/<api_key_goes_here>/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
```